# "Messages" has grown in size

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

As you can see:

[image: Messages]

The "[Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox)" *header* has font size much higher than the others, for eg:

All Questions:

[image: All Questions]

Tags:
[image: Tags]

---

It might be a trivial thing, but looks fixable within a short span of 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Where is this header? I don't see a red freehand circle..

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ink  :(