# Stack Overflow Jobs Update - February 2019

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, announcement

Here’s a roundup of what’s happened on Jobs lately, plus some insights into what’s coming up.

---

#### Improvements to Company Pages

After shipping a large design update to company pages last August, [Kirti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012097/kirti-thorat?tab=profile) and [Courtny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3281191/courtny?tab=profile) continued to iterate on them over the past few months. Changes include:

- Better placement of cover photos
- Separating photos and videos into their own sections
- Ability to share and report company pages
- Improvements to the “people” section:

[image: Company Pages with the new "People" section]

We will continue to make improvements to company pages through most of 2019, and it’s an area that we are currently focused on. We’re exploring ways to encourage companies to share more useful and interesting content from their software teams.

---

#### Responsive Design

[Aurélien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370722/aur%C3%A9lien-gasser?tab=profile), [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6347688/ian?tab=profile), and [Piper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7851896/piper-lawson?tab=profile) shipped several updates towards the end of 2018 making more of the site responsive. Most notably, search filters were overhauled, making them easier to discover and easier to use on smaller screens:

[image: New search filters on a smaller screen size]

The “Messages” section largely remains unchanged (and in [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371830/messages-has-grown-in-size) [cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374244/jobs-messages-section-design-is-weird) [badly broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379022/user-experience-on-getting-to-job-applications-messages-needs-work-and-there-are)).

The messages module is an older part of our platform, and... let’s just say that it hasn’t aged gracefully. Changes in this section often introduce regressions and we needed to carve out some time to sort it out.

While technical debt is something we all deal with, it’s not an excuse, and we intend to fix this incrementally over the coming months. In fact, [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson?tab=profile) and [Courtny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3281191/courtny?tab=profile) are already tackling some of the biggest bugs and should have some updates before the end of this month.

In the meantime, thank you to those of you who wrote us about this, and for your patience as we work through it.

---

#### Salary Calculator

Back in September, [Gervasio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920295/g3rv4?tab=profile) updated the [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) with data from the 2018 developer survey. We added support for eight new countries and made several refinements to our model.

For more details, [check out this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/05/developer-salaries-in-2018-updating-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/) or give the [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) a try.

---

#### Syndication & Job Quality

One of the main pain points we keep hearing is that we don’t have enough jobs and companies listed on Stack Overflow. Addressing this is one of our main objectives in 2019 and we’re exploring several solutions including syndicating jobs from partners in the space.

Syndication allows us to quickly provide a lot more jobs in places we historically haven’t had many opportunities. In the past few months, we ran experiments with a few partners including [LinkedIn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378194/what-would-be-the-point-of-sending-users-over-to-linkedin/378779#378779) and [InfoJobs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/31/stack-overflow-infojobs-bringing-opportunities-to-developers-in-spain/).

However, there’s a downside: job quality becomes harder to control.

We want to make sure we’re able to consistently identify high-quality listings and successfully filter out irrelevant or fake listings. Our goal here is to grow the job board with **quality** listings.

Hence, we’re investing heavily in our ability to filter out low-quality listings and improve our overall job discovery experience. We plan to experiment with new features on this front over the coming months.

In the meantime, if you come across a listing that you think shouldn’t be there, please report it. We review every single one of these reports and it helps us better identify the kinds of listings we should automatically filter out.

For now, we plan to continue iterating, gathering feedback and data so that we can decide if syndication is worth pursuing further and optimizing.

---

As always, we’d love to hear from you. If you have any thoughts or feedback to share, please post it as an answer below.

<3

The Talent Team

Comment: This is great stuff! Well, I couldn't care less about the Salary Calculator. But the focus on increasing the number of *quality* jobs is right-on. Either way, thank you to you and the team for your hard work, and also for keeping us all updated on your progress and goals.

Comment: A little over a year ago I gave my feedback on what I thought about some of the UX/UI. Since then it would seem a lot of work was put into it and wanted to say thank you for your hard work. Also the Jobs Update 2020 is overdue!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @kemicofaghost, I passed it along to our team. Glad we were able to address some of those long-standing UX pain points! As for 2020, as you can imagine, it's been quite the unpredictable year. We've rolled out quite a few incremental updates though the year, we'll look at maybe doing a roundup post like this in the coming months.

Answer (score 16):

Jobs as a platform is still completely useless to me, as long as I [can't filter jobs on *daily* salary instead of *annual* salary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338093/allow-specifying-minimum-monthly-and-daily-compensation-in-addition-to-annual-c). Perhaps freelancers are not part of your target audience?

Comment: hi @user247702 – I'm sorry for the really late response here. I totally missed the notification on this and only saw it once you commented on the post the other day. The vast majority (~97%) of jobs on the board today are full-time opportunities, so most current jobs define salary either monthly or annually. We've considered adding in better controls for hourly or daily rates, but it's not something that we are prioritizing this year. If more users see value in it, we can revisit it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it's a chicken and egg problem, if the system doesn't make it easy to post such jobs, then employers won't be eager to do so.

Comment: You're right. We'll continue to keep an eye on it. To be honest, we haven't seen much feedback from either side (employers or candidates) yet asking for more functionality around freelance / contract roles. But it's a large part of the industry, so I imagine we'll move towards it at some point. Unfortunately, I don't really have a concrete answer for when that might be.

Answer (score 5):

It might be useful to include "smaller" companies if you want truly want to address that "we don’t have enough jobs and companies listed on Stack Overflow".

**There's no quicker way to get more companies listed than to allow a greater diversity of companies to post listings.**

My current employer just tried and had [an off-putting experience similar to the one reported here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409169/how-do-small-companies-post-jobs-on-stack-overflow):

> Thank you for contacting Stack Overflow Talent.
>
> We know that hiring developers and technologists is a priority for you.
>
> Unfortunately, we don’t have product solutions that are a fit for you at this time. Our products are suited for mid-size or large companies that have employer branding and company awareness needs. We aren’t selling job slots to advertise job openings.
>
> We wish you the best in your hiring journey!
>
> Cheers,
> Stack Overflow Talent

If you only take big fish where you can build a relationship to make it easier to vet the quality of their job postings, I get it, but, as you note, if you're still syndicating jobs, that's automation, not bespoke listings.

There's a middle ground -- let companies smaller than [I'm not sure, but the number's north of 250] post (and pay for!) their listings using an automated form.

Also, your denial email should be more informative than this one. Frankly, it's too easily read as offensively dismissive. I'm not the HR director that received it (who, along with my manager, felt dismissed), but even at a distance I can see why they felt that way. They're not going to use you for "branding" when you're this callously dismissive of prospective [even if only with growth in the future] customers.

At *least* tell folks what fry-sized looks like. Or, if the decision was based on factors other than size, as [that previous meta post suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409169/how-do-small-companies-post-jobs-on-stack-overflow), say what those are. Right now you're cutting off your future clients to spite your face.

Better yet, *tell them on the [signup page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409169/how-do-small-companies-post-jobs-on-stack-overflow)*. It borders on a [dark pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=dark+pattern+ui) to pretend anyone can sign up the way it's presented now.

Or give them another option. If [using a recruiter allows them entry to SO Jobs through a side door](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409220/1028230), tell them that.

> Our goal here is to grow the job board with quality listings.

Let's shoot straight: **Maximizing quality job listings from diverse sources is at cross-purposes with the current goal of only serving large (?) companies that want and can pay for bespoke *branding*.** jobs.stackoverflow.com should be primarily about jobs, not branding.

---

Further, as an almost daily SO user, I can say with 100% certainty that **I haven't seen any company branding that's moved my needle**.

That's not a challenge beyond a challenge to refocus.

*I'm interested in finding good jobs (and hiring others looking for the same thing), just like the ones you said you wanted to provide in the original post.*

Appreciate the chance to weigh in.

Comment: _"callously dismissive"_, _"offensively dismissive"_, I think you're significantly overthinking the automated response. Now what exactly are you suggesting here, if anything?

This "Answer" reads more like a rant than feedback.

Comment: @Cerbrus That was HR's and my manager's response. I said "I can see that it's too easily read as". But even if you don't buy that, it's hardly a rant. The points are **1.** if you want more "jobs and companies listed", you allow smaller companies, and, related, **2.** A primary focus on branding does not jibe with "Our goal is to grow the job board with quality listings". (And, again, at least anecdotally, that branding is failing.) But **TL;DR:** Get that middle way of automation + diversity by adding  job-only listings and fix the grey (?) patterns in email & signup.