# Add reasoning on what the job reactions mean

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs, a-b-testing, reactions

What do the following job reactions mean?

[image]

The first three are obvious. What does it mean if I give a job a unicorn?
What about crying hysterically. And doesn't :( mean thumbs down?

This is very confusing. At least some tooltips would help, right?

Comment: the unicorn reaction must mean "too good to be true", or maybe "this job doesn't exist".

Comment: I just don't understand why there is so many different options - I mean really who would come up with such a confusing scenario - how did this pass user testing?  At most there should be 3, good, bad, neutral - the rest is just fluff.

Comment: @Patrick - or it could mean the job is magical in a spooky sense.

Comment: Where do you see job reactions? I can't find it on job postings, is this only shown to employers?

Comment: No I simply clicked on a job it was on the right side.

Comment: Are these reactions used for anything?

Comment: If they are only used as feedback for other job searchers, certain level of ambiguity is fine. If you see a job where most reactions are “laughing hysterically “, you kinda know what it means.

Comment: Not intrested. Unicorn 0.

Comment: Not a full answer, but this feature is being A/B tested, which is why only some users see it.

Comment: If this is implemented and favorable, then maybe we can have [this feature on SE posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309718) too...

Comment: Maybe :( means "had a bad experience with this job" (and <3 means "had a good experience with this job"). But yes, I agree that the unicorn and the hysterical crying aren't particularly useful. Can't answer for sure though, I'm not part of the test.

Comment: Anyway, for those who aren't part of the test, the SVG name for each image: thumbsup, thumbsdown, heart, unicorn, funny, sad.

Comment: React "sad" if reading the ad made you sad. React "thumbsdown" if reading the ad made you point your thumb down. Still confused?

Comment: Given the history of SO - some of its memes include unicorns and waffles.. I'd take a wild stab that the unicorn is a kind of "super heart". If I'm wrong, then I have no bloomin' idea what it's meant to be, and if I'm right, then I'm not massively surprised unless that you're an "old-timer" (and have read around a lot) on SO, what it's possibly meant to mean.

Comment: However, having said that, (and I don't want to hijack your post here JonH), I would be curious to hear from @AurélienGasser why there's even six options and what the jobs team is thinking about here?

Comment: React "thumbs up" if you're left-handed, "thumbs down" if right-handed.

Comment: Did they just port this over from GitHub post reactions without any changes?

Comment: @Jon that is fair, knowing Stack's story with unicorns... However, if the intent of these is to provide feedback to the job poster, what do *they* see? '10 people found your job posting amazing' is helpful. '10 people found your job posting [unicorn]'.... Not so much

Comment: @TylerH No, GitHub has eight.

Comment: My guess is that the last three are going to turn out to be like poking on Facebook: they don't have an assigned meaning; they're waiting to see how people use them. Personally, I'd use thumbs down for, "I don't like this", and the sad face for, "*No one* should like this". Unicorn would mean it had something that's hard to find.

Comment: You nailed it BSMP! We're curious and like to observe how folks decide to use them. Loving this discussion that shares so many rich thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand what this  reaction means, and my lack of understanding doesn't bother me at all. Quite the contrary: this mysterious reaction is very interesting _because_ it's mysterious. I wonder what kind of jobs would get ed! Also,  and  reactions are as straightforward as boring.

Comment: @JonClements see I am an old timer and have read a lot (an interacted a lot with others as you know) and I thought the "unicorn" was a *really bad thing* (as in these people want a "code ninja" or **super star, ultra-from-the-90s codemonkey** - related suggestion: add a monkey  ;P

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I'm currently using them (my opinion):

- **Thumbs up:** I like the job, but it doesn't mean I'd apply to it (maybe it's not my role or level).
- **Thumbs down:** I dislike the job. Maybe it's an industry or company I'm not willing to work, or the office location.
- ❤️ Heart: I loved the job and I'm definitely applying to it if I fit all requirements.
- **Unicorn:** The requirements are extremely hard to fit, very few people could apply to it.
- **Laughing:** The job is absurd, a complete joke. The requirements make no sense or don't fit the level at all (e.g asking 10+ years experience for a junior role), or there are too many gramatical errors, or the description is not related to the role or techs tagged. People should not pay attention to this job.
- **Sad:** I like the job, but I'm disappointed with something, maybe one specific requirement that do not allow me applying to it (e.g. some skill or the place I live).

---

### Why I'm using them

The reason I'm reacting to jobs is because I believe SO may use this in the future to understand how I feel about jobs and use some ML to recommend better jobs for me. It can also help recruiters to better understand how people feel about the job.

### Shouldn't Unicorn be for a dream job?

In my opinion it should not. For a dream job I'd use the Heart reaction.

### Unicorn vs Laughing

The difference is that a unicorn job might be doable for very few people. I don't see a unicorn job necessarily as bad or impossible. Laughing on the other hand is just absurd, it's my way of telling other people they should not pay attention to that job.

### Are these the correct meanings?

Not at all, I just wanted to share my opinion, as it may be useful for the staff and other people. The idea is to discuss and elaborate on the subject. I like to think that any "reactions" feature in any platform has no right/wrong way of using, since they just represent your emotions in relation to something (e.g. a job), and emotions are very personal.

As I said, this is only my opinion, as this question has [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, I thought it'd be fine sharing it.

Comment: The thing is that the unicorn vote has different meanings. It all depends of the user's interpretation to it, which introduces a bias in the data. Or noise. The person that has setup the feature answered with a non-answer. I also don't see value being added with the last two vote options, the  and  (seems as a worried emoji to me...) one. I am not a data scientist, but it happens that I have to do some data mining. I would have lots of "[wtf's](https://mk0osnewswb2dmu4h0a.kinstacdn.com/images/comics/wtfm.jpg)" with this...

Comment: @KarelG you're right about the bias and noise in the data, I agree. However when you introduce reactions in any platform I think this is expected, as they represent the user's emotions and this is personal, even if the person that had setup the feature had explained each one objectively, a data scientist would probably never expect users to follow it strictly, as this is not guaranteed to happen.

Answer (score -14):

Job reactions are a new feature that we're testing at the moment. They are currently visible to approximately half the users on Jobs. This is one of the ideas we're experimenting with as part of our [push to measure and maintain job quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380410/stack-overflow-jobs-update-february-2019) as we grow the job board.

Several factors affect job quality, some of which are easier to detect automatically. For example, a listing with barely any description or a listing that has nothing to do with software are much easier to classify as low quality in an automated way. Beyond this, applications and dismissals are the only signal we have on how candidates feel about listings. That's what we're hoping to learn with job reactions.

If we see enough engagement with this feature, we plan to iterate on it. This includes experimenting with the specific reaction types. The current set of reactions is our first attempt at the problem and we didn't want to be prescriptive at this stage with a strict positive/neutral/negative system. Hence, we included the 'heart', 'sad', and 'laughing' reactions. As for the unicorn? Sparkles just had to make an appearance!

At this time, we aren't sharing this data with employers and we aren't using this data in our search or matching algorithms. With this initial test of reactions, we wanted to learn about what gets candidates to... well, to react.

Tooltips are a good suggestion to help users identify the different reaction types. We'll keep that in mind for our next iteration on this feature.

Comment: But you really should at least tell us what each means if you want to "iterate" on it, don't ya think?  I mean how are you going to run stats and understand that 40 unicorn clicks meant the job was a dream or the job was some sort of fairy tale bs?  You answered the question and you still didn't state what each means...so the users will still not use it correctly.

Comment: This is altogether opposite of any initiative to maintain quality. You aren’t going to get quality feedback if no one can puzzle out what the feedback options mean, much less if everyone has a different interpretation of their meaning. Unicorn jokes and memes are fine on Meta or special occasions, but they’re not appropriate on the Jobs site. Deploying a half-baked feature that [even team members admit they aren’t sure what it means or is intended to be used for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/383038/384211#comment691056_383038) is distressingly unprofessional.

Comment: @JonH – we didn't want to be prescriptive to begin with. At this stage, we're more curious about what resonates with users and learning why. This will inform the follow-up research we then conduct. As for our current thoughts on reactions, 'like' and 'heart' are generally seen as positive indicators; 'dislike' and 'sad' are seen as negative; 'laughing' and 'unicorn' have no specific interpretation. We expect to refine this to be more objective before we rely on this feature for measuring quality or use in search/matching. We're still in the early stages here to gauge how users respond to it.

Comment: @CodyGray – thanks for the feedback. That's exactly why we're running this as a test: to better understand how users would engage with a feature like this. We haven't graduated it to be a standard feature of the platform and would expect to refine it significantly before using it as a reliable means of measuring quality.

Comment: If you're curious what sorts of feedback you might get, a better way to gauge that would be to provide a free-form textbox and let users type into it. You could then have your in-house data analysts process it, see what messages get submitted most often, and develop a full-fledged feature based around that. I really don't know what you expect to find when people say "this job makes me feel unicorn", and I'm concerned that any meaning you *do* extract from it will be misleading.

Comment: Gets answer that didn't want, comments that answer didn't help, gets comment that didn't help, gets secondary comment which still doesn't help...I give up "To better understand how users would engage with a feature like this..."  Damnit I am a user and I am telling you I don't know how to engage with it because I don't know what it means...sheshh -1!

Comment: @CodyGray – that's a good idea. We did consider it but ultimately punted on it for the initial version to reduce scope. We might add that in in a future iteration. And yes, we're being careful not to read too much into the use of the unicorn :) The only thing we're looking at right now is: "do people even use this?"

Comment: Sorry you feel that way @JonH. There's not much more I can add here. We're learning about how people want to use this feature, and your feedback above about what you found confusing was noted and helpful, so thank you.

Comment: 

Comment: I'd vote `Unicorn` on this answer, but the sparkle's button is missing.

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani We understand you want feedback, sure, but without explaining the selection how do you even know what your feedback is meant to mean? So, without the user knowing that the unicorn means 'dream job' how would you know that's what the user meant? Contrasting that with the thumbs up, thumbs down, and heart you can very clearly narrow down the feedback to know that if it is thumbs up, the user liked it, if it is thumbs down, the user didn't like it, and if it is a heart, then the user loved it. Do see how that feedback is understandable because the underlying implication...

Comment: behind each icon is actually known (universally) by both the the people reading the feedback data ***and*** the user who is giving the data? Whatever feedback you are currently getting can't seriously be used as valid data because the original users weren't aware of what each icon meant thereby rendering the collected data useless.

Comment: Maybe the feedback they're searching for isn't if users use them as they want them to use it but what does it means to them without giving an explanation (?... Something like _How many users think the unicorn one is for jobs that are too good to be real and how many use it to express that it's their dream job_ --EDIT: Just saw [BSMP's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383038/add-reasoning-on-what-the-job-reactions-means#comment689466_383038) and that was what I intended to say, I think it's better expressed there

Comment: I am really starting to wonder about this network sometimes. User gives great feedback about why something is nonsensical, and it's just swept away with non-answers. There is literally zero good reasons why a "unicorn" reaction is helpful. Absolutely none. Especially when no one knows what it means. "It's OK, we'll iterate!" Over what exactly? You are telling me not one person in getting this to this point stood up and said "no one is going to understand this"?

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani It is unclear who this feedback is intended too : site staff, fellow users, company itself ? If i "heart" a job listing, should I expect to see this company more often for example, should I expect others see it more ? IMHO re-using social network codes for non-social features gets in the way of understanding what's going on.