# Reactions to this job

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Is there any good reason for having these "Reactions to this job" feature? Does the company that posted the job see who reacted and how to their job posting?

Comment: [Nobody has any clue what these reactions mean, including the team responsible for introducing them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383038/add-reasoning-on-what-the-job-reactions-mean#comment691056_383038). So, [if you've ever wanted to tell a prospective employer that a job makes you feel really unicorn, now's your chance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383038/add-reasoning-on-what-the-job-reactions-mean#comment691090_384211). We'll all take guesses about what it might mean.