# Duplicated master data of companies, universities, etc. in Developer Story

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story

Developer Story suggestions contain a lot of duplicated master data, e.g. companies, universities:

[image: Harvard University duplicate entries sample]

Of course, there might be the same university but different schools/faculties, but since this field is intended to state the university/institution name and there is just one Harvard University, there should be just one single option.

It would be great to make a housekeeping and eliminate duplicate entries.

Comment: Relevant: It was recently [revealed by animuson in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/862604) that the Developer Story (and the Jobs section as a whole) will be discontinued no later than April of '22, less than a year from now.

Comment: @zcoop98, that's pity. I loved the way the SO CVs look like, optimal for IT/SWE related domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an artifact of how we designed the system to work in this case. Users are free to type in their own university or company name there, assign a picture and other details, and use in on their developer story. When they do that, it becomes available for everyone else to choose from. When users do not actually choose from an existing option and keep re-entering the same names - or maybe the logo was wrong so they created a new one, whatever the reason - then you end up with lists of the same things in the suggestions.

There isn't a lot we can do about this in our current system. The current "lists" system that governs that suggestion box is the result of a larger project that never succeeded being scaled down to the bare minimum. Then there were plans to just drop them and have users connect to Company Pages in Jobs instead, which also never materialized. We generally never got involved in making changes or consolidating those lists and have no interest in starting to do that given, as mentioned in the comments, Jobs is being discontinued and that consolidation work would be rendered moot in the future.

Even if we did consolidate all of these into one, there's nothing that would prevent this just happening again. As I mentioned, you can ignore the suggestion prompt and enter your own information to create another list. And people will continue to do that without us completely rewriting how those lists are suggested and created.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, since this module is going to be removed, then there is no reason to elaborate this issue. In a case this module would continue to exist, I would propose to make some housekeeping job, which will automatically make a merge or at least prepare a list of items for a manual check by a human.

Comment: There is no chance that the developer story will continue to exist once Jobs is sunset. It represents too great a security risk to keep all that personal information sitting around when we have no purpose for it. We are planning to quite literally drop all those tables from the database - you won't even be able to download backups once it has been removed.