# Share tag page in message from company in Jobs

Tags: bug, tags, stack-overflow-jobs, hyperlinks, jobs-messages

In Stack Overflow Jobs when sharing a link to a tag such as

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5675325+[php]
```

then the last square bracket isn't considered as part of the url

[image]

In this case, the link is then seen as

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5675325+[php
```

Due to that, clicking on it redirects the company to a page which isn't the one desired

[image]

Comment: Related: As mentioned in [this commen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/862604)t and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411253) by animuson, Jobs (and the associated Developer Story section) are being discontinued. No idea where that puts bug reports for either of those platforms in the meantime, however.