# Share link to tags in LinkedIn messages

Tags: bug, tags, hyperlinks, tag-search

A few days ago I noticed a [bug in the messages of Jobs when sharing the URL for searching by user tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411309/5675325).

The same problem happens when sharing tag links in the chat of LinkedIn.

[image]

Comment: `...in the chat of LinkedIn`; could you clarify what you mean by this?  I ask as it sounds as if you're reporting a bug from another unrelated website.

Comment: @Daedalus with that I mean the URL pattern we're using with the + creates problems not only in the Job's messages but in other systems too. Guess what I try to say is if another pattern could be used that's more friendly (without having to break in other systems, like a plain URL)

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the `+` character is a very common url token.  I don't think SO is wrong for using it, and I think the onus in this case lies with LinkedIn to fix the bug, not SO for using what [is defined in the w3c as valid](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html).

Comment: @Daedalus you can write that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, at least not on SO’s part.

The `+` sign just means "whitespace" on a URL. If LinkedIn fails to interpret it correctly, please report it to Microsoft, and I'm sure they'll fix it ASAP.

You could try with an alternative URL representation.

E.g.:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5675325%20[php]
```

(Note that this is just encoding a blank space, not a plus sign, which would be encoded as `%2b`, but it would not get you the results you want.)

This is equivalent to the URL you are trying to use:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5675325+[php]
```