# What does Stack Overflow Jobs' "Easy Apply" look like to a recruiter?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

When sending an application as an email, I know roughly what the recruiter's experience will be using their email application.

In using the "Easy Apply" feature I wonder what the recruiter sees so I can best tailor my application to them. Does it just get bundled up in a rich email with relevant attachments, or is there a backend that provides other features and links to the relevant posting?

Comment: Considering that Jobs is not longer being "sold" and that the entire section will die [very soon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409169/how-do-small-companies-post-jobs-on-stack-overflow), I don't know if it matters much right now. It's weird that there is still no mention of Jobs being discontinued in the Jobs page...